# How to integrate WebRTC with ios app swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I need to create an app that holds audio and video calling functionality. Does anyone have idea about which is a free library for this functionality ? And how to manage it properly in my app ?

Comment: Can you suggest some links which help me?

Comment: In GitHub demo project is not worked well for audio and video both.

Answer (score 1):

I used [AppRTC](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AppRTC) in my projects

You should implement `ARDAppClientDelegate` and `RTCEAGLVideoViewDelegate` protocols on `ViewController` on order to use this library.

You can find Swift examples on [Github](https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=ARDAppClientDelegate&type=Code)

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew for the suggested link. This is only for a video I also need for audio as well.

Comment: [ARDAppClient.h](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/blob/master/Lib/ARDAppClient.h) can work with audio. You should search usage examples like [this](https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=ARDAppClientDelegate+unmuteAudioIn&type=Code)

Comment: Okay, @Andrew let me check about it.

Comment: Link contains information about only video call I think it works well.